# How to verify FBInstant.context.getID() on the server side to ensure it is not faked?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

I have a multiplayer word game in "Facebook Web Games" format and would like to port it to "Instant Games".

The player id can be fetched by using `FBInstant.player.getID();` and then I could call an URL on my game backend server as in:

```
FBInstant.startGameAsync()
  .then(function() {

  var playerName = FBInstant.player.getName();
  var playerPic = FBInstant.player.getPhoto();
  var playerId = FBInstant.player.getID();

  $.post("/my/game/backend", { playerID: playerID });
});
```

But I don't understand, how to verify the player id at my backend server.

If I don't do that, someone else could just use `curl` to fetch the URL "/my/game/backend" and impersonate some other player.

There must be some kind of signature or token, which could be passed to the game backend server for verification using a common secret, but I cannot find it in the [Instant Games documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/sdk/fbinstant6.3) yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/sdk/fbinstant6.3#signedplayerinfo

> **SignedPlayerInfo**
> Represents information about the player along with a signature to verify that it indeed comes from Facebook.

You need to use `getSignedPlayerInfoAsync`, then you can get the signature from that, and send that value to your server to verify it there.

Comment: Thanks, when should I call `getSignedPlayerInfoAsync()`? Can it be done in `FBInstant.startGameAsync()`?

Comment: Don’t really know that, sorry. But I guess that should work, `FBInstant` already exists, and I would assume `FBInstant.player` as well at this point, don’t see the docs saying anything about that being available at a later point only.